# How to change the text's position in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Normally, in a JTextArea, the text starts in the upper left corner. I want it to be in the lower left corner. How can you do this?

[image]

(apologies if my handwriting is unreadable)

Comment: +1 for the hand-drawn diagrams.

Comment: as a straightforward decision: count the number of lines, fill the rest area with empty lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could anchor a `JTextArea` to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` location of a container and allow the text to scroll up.

[image: Amazing Base JTextArea Application]

```
public class BaseTextAreaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Base JTextArea App");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JPanel textAreaPanel = getBaseTextArea();
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textAreaPanel)  {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 230);
                    }
                };

                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

            private JPanel getBaseTextArea() {
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.append("bla bla bla\n");
                textArea.append("new text here");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setBackground(textArea.getBackground());
                panel.setBorder(textArea.getBorder());
                textArea.setBorder(null);
                panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                return panel;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` from the textArea in the JPanel that changes the positioning of the text?

Comment: In Ubuntu, [`textArea.getBackground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground()) returns its parent's background color, making the colors different: Very light gray panel, and white text area.

Comment: @Lonenebula In that case use `UIManager.getColor("TextArea.background")`

Comment: @Creator13 Give the `JScrollPane` a preferred size rather than the `JTextArea` panel. See update