# JScrollPane behaves unnormally with JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextfield

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800125/how-to-change-the-texts-position-in-a-jtextarea) before, on how to make a JTextField insert its text from beneath. Now I got some problem with the code. I edited a little bit, just for testing. Here is the code I'm using right now:

```
public class BaseTextAreaDemo {

private static JTextArea textArea;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Base JTextArea App");
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel textAreaPanel = getBaseTextArea();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textAreaPanel)  {
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(300, 230);
                }
            };

            panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    textArea.append(arg0.getActionCommand() + "\n");

                }

            });
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private JPanel getBaseTextArea() {
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.append("bla bla bla\n");
            textArea.append("new text here");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBackground(textArea.getBackground());
            panel.setBorder(textArea.getBorder());
            textArea.setBorder(null);
            panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            return panel;
        }

    });

}
```

I just added a textField, because I also need one in the program I need this in, and it's useful to add more lines this way.

Now the problem is, when I run this program and I add lines until a vertical scrollbar appears, a horizontal comes out too. I already figured that you can just turn that off, but then some text falls out of the screen. Also, when you make the frame wider, and than return it to it's normal size, the horizontal scrollbar stays at the size from the widened window.

[image: Some pictures of the problem]

Another problem is that the speed of scrolling is very low in the JTextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the PreferedSize of the textArea to the same as ur JScrollPane:

```
textArea.setPreferedSize(Dimension(300, 230));
```

You can aswell just disable Horizontal Scrollbar:

```
scrollPane.setHorizonalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

You can set the Scrollspeed like this:

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
```

i could solved the problem: its the panel u are adding to the scrollpane. Add the JTextArea directly to the ScrollPane and the Horizonal Bar only appear if needed:

```
textArea = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

Comment: I don't want to disable the horizontal scrollbar, because then the text will fall of the screen. The textfield will still be bigger than the shown area of it.

Comment: @CaspervanBattum Then just set the textField to a constant dimension value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fully remove the horizontal scrollbar then I suggest you invoke this line of code on your `JScrollPane`:

`scrollPane.setHorizonalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`