# Force JTextArea to the bottom of JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I've got the following code:

```
public class LobbyView extends JPanel
{
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    private final JTextArea chatWindowMessage = new JTextArea();
    private final JScrollPane chatWindow = new JScrollPane(chatWindowMessage);

LobbyView(Window sentWindow)
{
    chatWindow.setViewportView(chatWindowMessage);
    chatWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    chatWindow.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    chatWindowMessage.setLineWrap(true);
    chatWindowMessage.append("test" + "\n");
    chatWindowMessage.append("test 2" + "\n");

    this.add(chatWindow, "pos 180px 75px");
    this.add(chatMessage, "pos 180px 380px");
}
}
```

The code results in the following JScrollPane:

[image: JScrollPane]

**How do I force the JTextArea to the bottom of the JScrollPane so it looks like this (N.B. I use MigLayout):**

[image: JScrollPane2]

Comment: borderlayout for textarea and all rest nested in borderlayout center is cool ?

Comment: possible duplicate [How to change the text's position in a JTextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800125/how-to-change-the-texts-position-in-a-jtextarea)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add blank lines at the begining, depending on number of rows of JTextArea, and set the caret location to the end of the TextArea using setCaretPosition() method.

Answer (score 0):

To force `JTextArea` at the end of `JScrollPane`, you can make use of Layouts. [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) will do the job for you.